# .htaccess 301 redirect path and all child-paths

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want accesses to e.g. www.thisdomain.com/docs/path1/path2 to redirect to www.thatdomain.com/path1/path2

(Note that docs is not a part of the new path)

I have the following on www.thisdomain.com:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^docs/* http://www.domain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

If I access www.thisdomain.com/docs, it directs to www.thatdomain.com, but if I access a child-path like www.thisdomain.com/docs/path1/path2 it fails. Is it possible for the redirect to intercept the child-path access and redirect as I need? If so, any pointers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With regular expressions, * means any number *of the previous atom*, which will match /docs and /docs/. Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^docs$ http://www.domain.com/ [R=301,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^docs/(.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

(`QSA` is query string append, so `/docs/foo?bar=baz` won't lose the `?bar=baz`.)

Answer (score 2):

According to section "Redirect Old domain to New domain using htaccess redirect" of [the first Google result](http://www.webconfs.com/how-to-redirect-a-webpage.php) which I found searching for "htaccess redirect" (without the double quotes), this piece of code will suffice:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

According to their description of the technique, it will redirect the directory the .htaccess file is placed in recursively (including any child paths), just as you intend. Of course, mod_rewrite needs to be present for the rewrite directives to work.