# Redirect from default page to another page using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect the user from the default page `index.php` to another page.

i.e: `http://www.example.com/project/` to `http://www.example.com/project/main/ar/`

I tried this `Redirect / /main/ar/`, but insted it redirects to `http://www.example.com/main/ar/project/`

What is the wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try

```
Redirect /project/ /project/main/ar/
```

Depending of if you need to redirect all children paths of project you may want to look at this thread -> [.htaccess 301 redirect path and all child-paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181606/htaccess-301-redirect-path-and-all-child-paths)