# .htaccess 301 redirect, keeping paths

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to redirect www.olddomain.com/content/path to www.newdomain.com/content/path

Somehow:

> [.htaccess 301 redirect path and all child-paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181606/htaccess-301-redirect-path-and-all-child-paths)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/ [R=301]
```

Isn't working and is always redirecting to index.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because you're missing captured group `$1` in target URL:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

OR you can do:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ http://newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

anubhava,

What would be the difference between:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

OR you can do:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ http://newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```