# Apache > How to redirect the home page and others urls separately?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, seo, redirect

I'm currently dealing with a website overhaul in a special configuration : the 2 websites are hosted on 2 different servers with a new domain name for the new one.
The new domain is now online, so I have to redirect the old domain from the old server which is running on Apache 2.2.16.

Thus, I have to redirect the old domain home page to the new domain home page like this :

```
http://www.oldwebsite.com > http://www.newwebsite.com
```

And at the same time I have to redirect old urls separately one by one (for SEO purpose because new domain urls were optimized) like this :

```
http://www.oldwebsite.com/page1/ > http://www.newwebsite.com/newpage1/
http://www.oldwebsite.com/page2/ > http://www.newwebsite.com/newpage2/
http://www.oldwebsite.com/page3/ > http://www.newwebsite.com/newpage3/
http://www.oldwebsite.com/directory1/ > http://www.newwebsite.com/newdirectory1/
http://www.oldwebsite.com/directory2/ > http://www.newwebsite.com/newdirectory2/
http://www.oldwebsite.com/directory3/ > http://www.newwebsite.com/newdirectory3/
Etc.
```

Therefore, I put in the htaccess file on the old server these rules :

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.newwebsite.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^page1$ http://www.newwebsite.com/newpage1/? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^page2$ http://www.newwebsite.com/newpage1/? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^directory1(.*)$ http://www.newwebsite.com/newdirectory1/? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^directory2(.*)$ http://www.newwebsite.com/newdirectory2/? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^directory3(.*)$ http://www.newwebsite.com/newdirectory3/? [R=301,L]
Etc.
```

*Note : I added the "?" at the end of new urls to prevent transfer of old parameters in order to avoid duplicate content. I heard that this is the way to do it on former Apache versions.*

When I did so, only the home page was redirected and the others rules were not followed.
So I changed the order of the rules by getting the first rule to the end, like this :

```
RewriteRule ^page1$ http://www.newwebsite.com/newpage1/? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^page2$ http://www.newwebsite.com/newpage1/? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^directory1(.*)$ http://www.newwebsite.com/newdirectory1/? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^directory2(.*)$ http://www.newwebsite.com/newdirectory2/? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^directory3(.*)$ http://www.newwebsite.com/newdirectory3/? [R=301,L]
Etc.
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.newwebsite.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Now as a result, the home page is still redirected but the rest of urls respond with 500 error status.

Do anyone have any idea of what's wrong in my file ?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found this article that may solve your prob

[.htaccess 301 redirect path and all child-paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181606/htaccess-301-redirect-path-and-all-child-paths)

Use these lines of Code:

```
RewriteRule ^page1$ http://www.newdomain.com/ [R=301,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^page1/(.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```